# Querying and Mutating a Form with Apollo Client GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

The whole GraphQL paradigm is new to me, usually working with React Redux. My requirements are:

1. User clicks a Row Item w/ UID
2. We open a form to edit this data (with previously saved information pre-populated)
3. We then edit this data and save

I would think (2) & (3) would be handled by a `<Query><Mutation/><Query>` type of structure but it doesn't work, mainly because setting state in the Query will make the textinputs controlled inputs... controlled by `<Query>`, and I can no longer edit it.

Besides this, I've read that GraphQL removes the need for Redux, etc? So I'm reluctant to go around sticking this query in a middleware and propogating to Redux.

Any thoughts? This must be a common requirement. What have others came up with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data should be passed down as a prop to whatever component will actually render the form. Inside that component's constructor, you then set the initial state based on the props. A rough example:

```
class FormComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    this.state = this.props.initialState
  }

  render () {
    // Render form using this.state and this.props.update
  }
}

<Mutation mutation={SOME_MUTATION}>
  {(mutate) => (
    <Query query={SOME_QUERY}/>
      {({ data, loading, error }) => {
        if (loading) return <LoadingIndicator/>
        if (error) return <ErrorComponent/>
        if (data) return <FormComponent initialValues={data.someQuery} update={mutate}/>
      }}
    </Query>
  )}
</Mutation>
```

The mutation could go inside the Query, or inside the FormComponent itself -- that bit doesn't really matter. We're not rendering the FormComponent until we have data, so the initial values will always reflect the results of the query.