# How do you put apollo query data into a controlled input?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

So using Apollo's `<Query>` component, I can get data just fine. At some point I'm going to have to feed some of this data into a user input. I would like this input to be controlled which means the data needs to live in component state. So it seems like I need to convert the data from the Apollo query into component state, or more accurately, data from Apollo query -> passed down as component prop -> component state.

The only way I know how to achieve that is to use `componentDidUpdate` or `getDerivedStateFromProps`. The React docs make it very clear that using those functions are bad practices, especially when dealing with inputs... So how are we supposed to do this? I must be missing something really obvious here.

Comment: That's a good question. I think in that case putting the value you want to use in the `input` field, in the component's state is just just fine. And as you said controlling that input needs a controlled component. So, say you have a `App.js` that gets some data and renders a `Form.js` component, that has some input fields. If you structure you app in that way, I don't think you need to use `componentDidUpdate`, because once you get the data, pass it to the independent components, e.t. `Form.js` which in turns has its own state!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but with your explanation a props -> component state step still needs to happen. I was thinking about this more today, and I'm starting to wonder if this sorta thing calls for a manual query done by the apollo api in componentDidMount or something.

Comment: Yeah, I mean the `container` gets the data and `child` receives it ONCE as a props. Maybe it's a good idea to make a simple https://codesandbox.io/dashboard for that matter! If you do, please share it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to go this route:
[Querying and Mutating a Form with Apollo Client GraphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714452/querying-and-mutating-a-form-with-apollo-client-graphql)

Basically, wait till you have the data, then render your form/inputs. Pass the data from apollo down and set the initial state in the form/input constructor. Then use setState like normal.

I'm a little disappointed though because what if I wanted to update the data in the form from another graphql query after the first render? Seems like you're just out of luck in that case.

Comment: Why would that be a problem? You can just create a method that updates your data based on a given API!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue in a complex form where saving one value could potentially affect other input placeholder values. I still have controlled components, but just added `useEffect` to see if the value coming from Apollo has changed.

```
 const [value, setValue] = React.useState(apolloValue);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setValue(apolloValue);
  }, [apolloValue]);
```